# Laravel sometimes doesn't load new controller

Tags: php, laravel

I'm facing a problem in Laravel. It seems that sometimes the Laravel framework loads an old version of a controller.

I created a new function and sometimes Laravel found it and sometimes it returns that the method does not exist.

What could be the problem in this case?

This is my function:

```
public function test(){
    echo 'Here'; exit();    
    return view('welcome');
}
```

The Page sometimes show only `Here` (which is correct) and sometimes it redirects me to the welcome blade without showing the `Here` message.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. At this site, questions are expected to be accompanied by some attempt at a solution by the author. General questions on how to do something or requests for solutions will cause your question to be closed. 
Add some code of what are you trying to do.

Comment: Check the case of your route declaration and make sure it matches perfectly with controller/method... It is funny that laravel will find the controller and function of an unmatched case in a none  production environment but will not find it in a production environment

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are define the url in `web.php` within `route` folder

or use this command

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: It's defined in the web.php otherwise it won't redirect you to welcome blade it would show route not found exception, i'll try to clear the cache and config